# Post MicroBlog message which includes Hashtags - InsufficientPermissions Error

Tags: permissions, access-denied, social, social-tag, hashtags

I have a webpart in the master page which uses a jscript file to perform microblogging operations. This webpart has similar features like OOB NewsFeed part.
There is no problem if I create a post which includes Mention, Url SocialData items, but if the message contains a Hashtag, the following exception is occured.

> Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.CreatePost:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException:
>   InsufficientPermissions : ( Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) ) The current user is not authorized to
>   perform the operation.

I tried the code example which is found in MSDN and got same exception.

```
// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(PublishPost, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

// Declare global variables.
var clientContext;
var feedManager;
var resultThread;

function PublishPost() {

    // Initialize the current client context and the SocialFeedManager instance.
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    feedManager = new SP.Social.SocialFeedManager(clientContext);

    var socialDataItem = new SP.Social.SocialDataItem();
    socialDataItem.set_itemType(SP.Social.SocialDataItemType.tag);
    socialDataItem.set_text('#hashTag');    
    var socialDataItems = [ socialDataItem ];

    // Create the post content.
    var postCreationData = new SP.Social.SocialPostCreationData();
    postCreationData.set_contentText('The text for the post, which contains a {0}.');
    postCreationData.set_contentItems(socialDataItems);

    // Publish the post. Pass null for the "targetId" parameter because this is a root post.
    feedManager.createPost(null, postCreationData);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(PostSucceeded, PostFailed);
}   

function PostSucceeded(sender, args) {
    $get("spanMessage").innerText = 'The post and reply were published.';
}
function PostFailed(sender, args) {
    $get("spanMessage").innerText = 'Request failed: ' + args.get_message();
}
```

It works if I use this code in "MySite" collection.

What should I configure to send messages including hashtags in other site collections?

Answer (score 0):

and the answer to your question ;)

> To create an application page that uses the JavaScript object model to
> work with social feeds, you'll need:
>
> •SharePoint Server 2013 with My Site configured as public, with
> personal sites created for the current user and a target user, with
> the current user following the target user, and with a few posts
> written by the target user
>
> •Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013 with Office Developer Tools
> for Visual Studio 2012
>
> •**Full Control access permissions to the User Profile service
> application and permissions to deploy a farm solution for the
> logged-on user**
>
> •**Sufficient permissions for the application pool account to access the
> content database of the My Sites web application**

solution:

give access to the account:

```
#Grab a reference to the User Profile Service Application
$serviceapp = Get-SPServiceApplication | where {$_.DisplayName -eq "User Profile Service Application"}

#Return the SPObjectSecurity object for the Service Application
$security = Get-SPServiceApplication $serviceapp | Get-SPServiceApplicationSecurity

#Setup our claim provider
$claimprovider = (Get-SPClaimProvider System).ClaimProvider

#Specify the required principal
$principal = New-SPClaimsPrincipal "Domain\UPSAppAccount" -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName

#Grant the required permissions on the Service Application
Grant-SPObjectSecurity -Identity $security -Principal $principal -Rights "Full Control"
Set-SPServiceApplicationSecurity $serviceapp -ObjectSecurity $security
```

https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/adawson/post/2012/11/23/Setting-SharePoint-2013-User-Profile-Service-Application-Permissions-Using-PowerShell.aspx

[image]

dont know if this will work but you could add your application pool account to the list and give full control!

http://www.mavention.com/blog/granting-permissions-user-profile-service-application-powershell

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. 
All AppPool accounts have already "Full Control" Permission on User Profile Service Application, but still this exception appears.
As I have written, I have only problem with #hashtags. 
What I've seen in following link in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822975(v=office.15).aspx

Reply, like, and mention references are stored indefinitely in the user’s personal feed. **Tag references are stored in the Distributed Cache**, so they are stored temporarily.
Tags are something special..